# What is position:relative useful for?

Tags: css, css-position

I was thinking about CSS positioning modes today and realized that I never use  `position:relative` for anything other than making `position:absolute` work on child elements.

I'm more of a "developer" than a "designer", but I've done quite a few CSS-based layouts over the years. I've used tables, float, margins (positive and negative), position:absolute, and even position:fixed, but I don't think I've ever had an occasion where I've used position:relative for actually positioning an element.

Is there some great CSS-guru technique that relies on position:relative (and is used in real-world designs)? Am I missing out?

Comment: Well, you named it: offset `position:absolute`. Which is actually useful.

Comment: Agreed, but that usefulness doesn't really have anything to do with the actual functionality of position:relative. Hence the question. :-P

Comment: Well, it's clearly defined in the standards, and it's the only non-destructive way to do it, so I call it useful and an actual functionality. :)

Comment: You could use it to position your `1x1spacer.gif` as well, don't forget!

Comment: Heh, that's another good question: "Who still uses spacer gifs?" I haven't done that for a while now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's useful if you want to offset an element without futzing around with margins and its consequences for other elements. Let's say you want to intentionally have an image poke out of the side of a container and (nearly) overlap with some content in a container beside it.

```
------------- -----
|           | |   |
|   X  -------| Y |
|      |  a  ||   |
|      -------|   |
------------- -----
```

Container `a` is part of the normal text flow of `X` and you want to keep it that way, you just want it poking out of the side a bit as a neat effect. If you do that with margins, it may get really messy and reflow some of your other content.
By using `position: relative; left: 10px;` you can get that effect easily without the side effects.

Answer (score 6):

I've used `posotion: relative` in the past for a container element, with absolutely positioned elements inside it (like a centered three column layout). For example:

[image]

I don't give the container any offset, but positioning it with `position: relative` allows me to absolutely position the columns relative to the container. If the container is set to `position: static`, as it is by default, then the columns will be absolutely positioned relative to the browser viewport, not the container.

Comment: excellent diagram helped me visualise my problem immediately. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I use `position:relative;` so that superscript characters can still ascend above `vertical-align: top;` but doesn't allow them to mess with the leading of my paragraphs.

```
sup { 
    font-size: .7em;
    vertical-align: top;
    position: relative;
    top: -.1em;
}
```

Comment: I figured there would be a typographical reason for doing so.

Answer (score 1):

I've used it more than once to display things like header images, something like:

```
<div id="header">
  <div id="logo"></div>
<div>
```

CSS:

```
#header { width: 1024px; margin: 0 auto; background: url(string.jpg); }
#logo { position: relative; left: 40px; background: url(logo.jpg); }
```

In this case the header has a large stripe all the way across as a background image, the logo sits in the stripe just offset a bit.  Simpler than padding/margin in some cases to shift stuff around a bit I think, maybe it's just opinion.

Comment: I'm not sure about "simpler", since it requires 2 CSS properties instead of one (relative to `margin-left: 40px`). If there's some other consequence of using position:relative then it may be worth considering... but so far they look identical to me.

Comment: @Craig - Another case is I've had a logo up top that overhung the wrap window for the entire site due to the logo style, so setting the div as `left:-20px;` gave far fewer issues than negative margins, but like I said, maybe just a matter of taste...I do use it rarely I admit, but it finds it's way into a stylesheet every once in a while.

Comment: That sounds like a great use to me.

Answer (score 1):

I mainly use it when I want to position some absolute element relative to its parent element. In that case the parent element need to be set to `position: relative`. That's where it is for.

Further I also use it here and there to fix IE6/7 haslayout/flickering bugs in block elements with a background image.